# How to add a wildcard to combobox-selected value to broaden values returned in multiple item form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have a multiple item form which displays client records, e.g., first and last name, date of birth, address, etc… The same client can be listed multiple times in multiple ways and may have the same or similar name as other clients (because bad historic data process). Jim Smith, James Smith, and Jim Smith Jr. could be the same or more than three different people (with date of birth and other information helping to resolve such issues).

I have set up two combo boxes to filter the form sequentially, but I need some help getting them to function as desired. The first combo pulls the list of distinct last names from the underlying table via a simple select query. Once a name is selected the second combo box offers the set of distinct first names with the selected last name.

Is there a way to use the selected last name plus wildcards in the vba so that selecting “Smith” would also return “Smith Jr.”, “Smith-Jones”, and “Smithers”? Right now I have the following which requeries the second combobox and sets the initial filter on the form, at the moment only to “Smith” in my example:

```
Private Sub cboFindLast_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cboFindFirst.Requery
    Me.cboFindFirst = Null
    Me.Filter = "LName = '" & Me.cboFindLast & "'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

This works as desired except for not returning the “Smith+” entries. At this point the user can select from cboFindFirst to reduce the list even more. Again, it would be nice if selecting “Ann” would return Ann, Anna, Annie, and even Ruth-Ann if any of those occur. The code currently on the second box is:

```
Private Sub cboFindFirst_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Filter = "FName = '" & Me.cboFindFirst & "' And LName = '" & Me.cboFindLast & "'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Again, this works well and reduces the list to e.g., all of the “Ann Smith” records, but maybe there’s a more recent “Annie Smith-Jones” after she was married and I’d like that record to show as well.

Comment: Why would 1 client have multiple names? There should be a client master record and then save that record ID key into related dependent records.

Comment: You are correct! There _should_ be. However I'm dealing with an old database I inherited and which is slated for archiving within about 2 years. This system receives data from several others and many of the admin staff are A) not very computer savvy, and B) entering information secondhand from an investigation. One investigator may meet "Jim Smith" and a year or two later, a different investigator will meet "James Smith" and each puts on their report what they are given. It is awful having to clean up after everyone. I'm making headway. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, use LIKE with wildcard:

`Me.Filter = "LName LIKE '" & Me.cboFindLast & "*'"`

`Me.Filter = "FName LIKE '" & Me.cboFindFirst & "*' And LName LIKE '" & Me.cboFindLast & "*'"`

Comment: Good grief... sometimes doing this makes me feel so dumb... I tried it with the wildcards but forgot the 'LIKE'. Thanks so much!